# Abstracting for-of loop out of class method calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using a class where each method operates on the same list, however, I am looking for an effective way to abstract out the looping feature of each method body because it is present in nearly every block.

For example, currently I am doing something like:

```
class example {
  constructor(list) {
  ....
  }
  ....
  someFunc(param) {
    for (let elem of this.list) {
      elem.doSomething();
    }
  }
  someOtherFunc(param) {
    for (let elem of this.list) {
      elem.doSomethingElse();
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to call these methods without use of the `for of` loop as it is resulting in redundant code. I was wondering I could achieve this any other way?

Comment: Make a method that iterates over the list and accepts a callback? Or directly use `this.list.forEach` if it's an array.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this and was kind of looking for a way that I could iterate in a different manner. I guess I will just create a new `forEach` method.

Comment: Well, you either have to use an actual loop statement or an API method that applies a function to every element. There isn't really anything else. Can you be more specific what you were looking for, maybe provide an example in a different language (where you might have seen whatever you are looking for)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take inspiration from `Array.prototype.forEach()` and implement an `.each()` method for your object:

```
class example () {
    each(callback) {
        for (let elem of this.list) {
            callback(elem);
        }
    }

    someFunc(param) {
        this.each(x => x.doSomething());
    }
}
```

If `list` is implemented an array and you only want to do the simple loop above then there's even better news, it's already implemented for you by `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```
class example () {
    someFunc(param) {
        this.list.forEach(x => x.doSomething());
    }
}
```

The custom `.each()` implementation of course allows you to do other things in the `for` loop so you can abstract away even more code.